# Spring Statemachine - Automatic Flow

Tags: spring, spring-statemachine

In my project I basically have these States:

S1, S2, S3, S4

When I send Event E1, there is a transition to S2. Now based on a choice, either the State is changed to S3 or it stays at S2. When there is a transition to S3 -> I would like again automatically forward to S4 or stay at S3, without any new event.

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two options.

- Define anonymous transition(no event) between `S3` and `S4` having a `Guard`. This transition is taken automatically if guard allows it.
- Other hack you can try is to use entry action in `S3`. You can send additional events from that action. This only works if you control events and know that there's no other events queued.